# Ping/Access Host Machine FROM Hyper-V VM

Tags: windows-8.1, hyper-v

I am not sure if this query is valid for this forum.

I have the following setup

```
1. Host Machine: Windows 8.1 Pro
2. Hyper-V enabled
3. VM [Windows 7] configured with internet access (using ICS from host machine, working fine)
4. RDP enabled to access VM from HOST
```

Now my question is how to configure Hyper-V in such a way that, from VM machine I will be able to access my Host machine Files, IIS, printer etc [IIS website is my primary focus]

Comment: Hello I think this question belongs on superuser.com . If you just want IIS you will be fine using ICS. But for sharing files and printers I would suggest that both machines are on the same subnet. Also Home Sharing requires IPv6 so you will do better by taking the little extra time of creating a Virtual Switch.

Comment: Thank you. Have posted in superuser.com also.

Answer (score 0):

You can only do this through the network layer by using IP address for example.

'VM to HOST' access through the virtualisation layer is impossible.

Comment: is there any specific reason for this?